# Need list of valid authentication_methods for docusign API for embedded signers

Tags: docusignapi, signing

I know that there is no authentication performed by Docusign when using embedded signers.  In the RecipientViewReuest it allows for an authentication_method.  So far I have found that 'none' and 'email' work fine.  I assumed that this was a free form text field that allowed me to say something like 'Checked their IDs'  But any I've used so far (besides none and email) cause an error,  so I assume there a limited list of acceptable answers.  Anyone know what they are?

Comment: Answered below. If it helps you out, be sure to upvote and accept. Thanks! –

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the following recipient authentication types on your envelope:

- Access Code
- Phone Authentication
- SMS
- Knowledge-Base Authentication(KBA)
- ID Verification (IDV)

In your case (for embedded signing) you have two separate API requests to make: The only change will come in your POST /envelopes call.

Ex. Let's say I wanted to [add an access code](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-access-code) to a particular recipient. Easy as adding the `accessCode` property when you create your envelope.

```
{
    "documents": [{
        "documentBase64": "JVBERi0xLjMNJeLjz...lRU9GDQo=",
        "documentId": "1",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "name": "Lorem"
    }],
    "emailBlurb": "Sample text for email body",
    "emailSubject": "Please Sign",
    "envelopeIdStamping": "true",
    "recipients": {
    "signers": [{
        "name": "{SIGNER_NAME}",
        "email": "{SIGNER_EMAIL}",
        "roleName": "",
        "note": "",
        "routingOrder": 1,
        "accessCode": "{ACCESS_CODE}"
        "status": "created",
                "tabs": {
                "signHereTabs": [{
                    "documentId": "1",
                    "name": "SignHereTab",
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "tabLabel": "SignHereTab",
                    "xPosition": "75",
                    "yPosition": "572"
                }]
            }
    }]
    },
    "status": "Sent"
}
```

Here is a [full guide on this topic](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/concepts/recipient-authentication).

Answer (score 0):

Matthew has provided the list of additional authentication that DocuSign can do for you if you wish.

Here is the list of authentications that you can list as having performed before calling the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) method.

They're listed on that page in the description for the `recipientViewRequest.authenticationMethod` attribute. Use the value that best describes the authentication that your application did.

- Biometric
- Email
- HTTPBasicAuth
- Kerberos
- KnowledgeBasedAuth
- None
- PaperDocuments
- Password
- RSASecureID
- SingleSignOn_CASiteminder
- SingleSignOn_InfoCard
- SingleSignOn_MicrosoftActiveDirectory
- SingleSignOn_Other
- SingleSignOn_Passport
- SingleSignOn_SAML
- Smartcard
- SSLMutualAuth
- X509Certificate